# dgemm or dgemv for Matrix Multiplication?

Tags: performance, lapack

I know `dgemv` is for matrix-vector, but which is more efficient? Using `dgemm` directly for matrix multiplication or using `dgemv` to do the matrix multiplication by multiplying the Matrix A with each individual column of matrix B using `dgemv`?

Answer (score 7):

If you make repeated calls to DGEMV, you will not benefit from cache tiling and re-use, which are the biggest advantages good DGEMM implementations have.  DGEMM is *vastly* more efficient than multiple calls to DGEMV.